# Regarding transit via HongKong

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, hong-kong

I am an Indian passport holder, currently living in Switzerland. I have a flight from Zurich to Auckland on 28th April, 2019 via Cathay Pacific and in-between, have the transit in Hong for 14 hours. I just wanted to know that if I stay at the airport and don't go out, do I still need a transit visa or PAR, as when I tried filling it, it came out to be unsuccessful? But, I have no plans to go out and roam around and would stay at the airport.

Comment: Welcome to NZ. I'm in Auckland. If you can get Hong Kong access it would be very worthwhile if you've not been there before. 14 hours is very ample to get a good 1st look at the city. Transport to and from the airport is fast and reliable - the train especially so.

Comment: Here are some things to see in Hong Kong - my answer and others relate - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/14502/3301

Comment: I also wanted to roam around the city but the point is that my PAR is coming out to be unsuccessful and if I apply for the visit visa now, it will take around 4-5 weeks and I have to fly on 28th April. So, I am not sure about getting my visa on time.

Comment: SOMETIMES a phone call can achieve what online processes cannot. If you qualify for PAR but the system is throwing your applications out for no good reason then a phone call MAY work. Or not. || If you are a "businessman" and *IF* your business may be of substantial benefit to Hong Kong (one can hope :-) ) then their Travel Pass may be available at the discretion of ???. Probably not, but ... .

Comment: No, I am not a businessman, just a student, planning a short vacation to NZ. I even tried calling them but they don't seem to respond well. When I explained them this situation that my PAR is coming out to be unsuccessful online, they simply say that they can't help it and thus, I will have to send everything by post, which to me seems cumbersome now. I called and even emailed them couple of times, but no fruitful response.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a visa, provided you remain in the international transit area of the airport.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
>   (Air-to-Air or Air-to-Sea) ticket to a third country within 48
>   hours. They must stay in the international transit area and
>   have documents required for the next destination.

You didn't ask, but in regard to New Zealand, if you have a visa but there is no visa label in your passport, you need to bring your visa approval letter.

> Visa Issuance:
>    New Zealand issues both printed visa labels and label-less
>     visas.  Printed visa labels are inserted into a passport or
>     travel document. There is no physical evidence of a
>     label-less visa in the passport or travel document but all
>     passengers must carry a printed visa approval letter that
>     confirms the details of their visa.
>
> The New Zealand visa record is held in Immigration New
>     Zealand's systems and authority to board should be verified
>     using the NZ APP system. Airlines not connected to NZ APP
>     that carry a passenger on an earlier leg of their journey,
>     can use TIETACNZ, or view the printed visa label or the visa
>     approval letter to identify any travel conditions, such as
>     whether the person is exempt from the requirement to hold a
>     return/onward ticket.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Yeah, I have the visa approval letter with me, since I applied online. So, that would be enough!

Comment: Just one more question, even PAR online is not required right? Because I tried filling it but it came out to be unsuccessful gain and again

Comment: @user94209 You don't need anything else for transit Hong Kong. The PAR is only needed if you cross immigration and enter Hong Kong officially.

Comment: okay. Thanks a lot again for clearing all the doubts. Thankyou so much