# Hong Kong International Airport Terminal 2 Closure

Tags: airports, layovers, hong-kong, opening-hours

As far as I understand, the IMAX theater and the Aviation Discovery Center are both located in Terminal 2.

Is the entire terminal closed during the renovations (November 2019 - 2024) or only certain parts?

Comment: Please keep to one question per question. In this case it is acceptable to ask whether the usual airport layover entertainments are still available. But a blanket "what is there to do" should be a different question (and we have one very much like it for Hong Kong that was recently active.)

Comment: Recent question (not a duplicate but might be helpful for ideas) https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/150205/what-can-i-do-at-hong-kong-airport-for-13-hours or run a search with Hong Kong and layover or some word like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the entire terminal and everything in it is closed for the duration. I can't find anything that actually *says* this though the [IMAX has no scheduled showings](https://www.imax.com/theatres/ua-imax-theatre-airport) for the foreseeable future and the relevant pages for everything in T2 have apparently been removed from the Hong Kong Airport web site as they now give 404 errors.

Comment: This is the what I also found during my research. Our 6 hour layover is this coming Friday so I'll report back on my findings.

Comment: Terminal 2 is closed along with everything inside it (IMAX, Aviation Discovery Center etc).